# C# best practice for performance: object creation vs reuse

Tags: c#, performance, object, reusability

I am currently working on performance tuning of an existing C# website. There is a class say.. MyUtil.cs. This class has been extensively used across all web pages. On some pages around 10/12 instances are created (MyUtil).  I ran the "Redgate" performance profiler. The object creation is a costly operation according to RedGate. 
Please note that each instance sets specific properties and performs specific operation. So I can not reuse the object as it is. I have to reset all the member variables.

I want to optimize this code. I have thought about following options. Kindly help me evaluate which is the better approach here :

(1) Create a "Reset" method in "MyUtil.cs" class which will reset all the member variables (there are 167 of those :(..) so that I can reuse one single object in an page class.

(2) Continue with the multiple object creation (I do have Dispose() method in "MyUtil")

(3) I thought of "object pooling" but again I will have to reset the members. I think its better to pool objects at page level and release them instead of keeping them live at the project level.

Any reply on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: what part of creation is expensive? is it the "figuring out what the 167 values should be" ? if so, can you perhaps *improve that* ? object creation *by itself* isn't all that expensive; if you still need to set the 167 values, some kind of pool is unlikley to help.

Comment: What exactly does your class actually do? Sounds like a poor architecture decision, but we can't really provide an answer if we don't know the specifics.

Comment: Given what little I know about MyUtil, it smells like a god class.

Comment: +1 to @MarcGravell, have you worked out how long the setting of those member variables takes?

Comment: I think your going to have to give us some more information if you want a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every app has multiple opportunities for speedup of different sizes, like kinds of food on your plate.
Creating and initializing objects can typically be one of these, and can typically be a large one.

Whenever I see that object creation/initialization is taking a large fraction of time, I recycle used objects.
It's a basic technique, and it can make a big difference.
But I only do it if I *know* that it will save a healthy fraction of time.
Don't just do it on general principles.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you always create new objects instead of resetting the objects. This is so for the following reasons

- GC is smart enough to classify objects and assign them a generation. It depends on the usage of objects in your code. Profiling is done based on the execution pattern of code as well as architecture of code
- You will be able to get optimum result from hardware if you use the GC and let it manage the process as it also decides the garbage collection thresh hold based on hardware configuration available and available system resources.
- Apart from that, your code will be much easier and manageable. - (Though it is not a direct benefit, but should also give at least some weight to it.)
- Creating object pool at page level is also not a good idea because to re-use the object, you will have to do two things, fetch it from pool and reset its properties, i.e. you will also have to manage the pool which is additional burden
- Creating a single instance and re-using it with resetting properties might also not be a good idea cause when you need more then one instance of object, it will not work.

so the conclusion is, you should keep creating objects in the page and let the Garbage collector do its job.